# Crossing out region on surface

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, regions, mesh, intersection

Consider the following Wolfram Mathematica code

```
Clear["Global`*"];



nn          = 3;
eps         = Table[Subscript[ep,i],{i,nn}];
xs          = Table[Subscript[x,i],{i,nn}];
alp         = 1/2;
bet         = 2;
Subscript[ep,2] = -alp Subscript[ep,1]/bet;
Subscript[ep,1] = 1;
Subscript[ep,3] = 0;

eqNcar      = -(1 + alp + bet)^(-1) - ((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) - Subscript[x, 1])^2 - ((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) - Subscript[x, 2])^2 + Subscript[x, 3];
eqNpar      = {w,s,w^2+s^2} + 1/(1+ alp+bet) {1,1,1};

eq1         = (-((1 + (1 + alp + bet)*s^2 + (1 + alp + bet)*w^2)*\
    (bet*s + s^2 + w*(alp + w))) + 2*s*(1 + (1 + alp + bet)*s)*\
   (s + alp*s^2 + w*(bet + alp*w)) + 2*w*(1 + (1 + alp + bet)*w)*\
   (alp*s + w + bet*(s^2 + w^2)))/(1 + alp + bet); 

eq2         = (alp*(-s + w)*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + s^2 + w^2) -
  (2*w*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + w)*(-(alp^2*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + s)) +
     bet*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + w)))/bet -
  (2*s*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + s)*(-(alp*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + s)) +
     bet^2*((1 + alp + bet)^(-1) + w)))/bet)*Subscript[ep, 1];

pN = ParametricPlot3D[eqNpar,{w,-1,1},{s,-1,1},\
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x,y,z,w,s},(eqNcar/. Thread[xs->eqNpar])-eq1],Function[{x,y,z,w,s},(eqNcar/. Thread[xs->eqNpar])-eq2]},\
  MeshStyle -> {{Blue},{Red}},\
  Mesh -> {{0}},PlotStyle->Orange,PlotPoints->200,
  BoundaryStyle->{1->None},\
  AxesLabel->xs
 ];

cm              = 72/2.54;
image       = Rasterize[Show[pN,ImageSize->10 cm],"Image",ImageResolution->800];
Export["ex.pdf", Show[image, ImageSize -> 10 cm]]
```

The cartesian of the surface $N$ is `eqNcar`.
I draw the intersections $N\cap E_1$ in blue and $N\cap E_2$ in red where the cartesian equations of $E_1$, $E_2$ are `eq1` and `eq2` respectively.

I would like to add a pattern on a specific region of $N$.
Namely, is is possible to color or to cross out or to draw white waves in the region :
$N\cap \{eq2<0\} \cap \{eq1>0\}$ ?

I tried using `RegionPlot3D` but I did not get acceptable results.
I also tried by defining a region with `Region` but it takes
a really long time to process the image (with `DiscretizeRegion`) and
the render was not good.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, w, s}, eq2 < 0 && eq1 > 0]`?

Comment: Or `MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {HalftoneShading[], 
   Automatic}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {HalftoneShading[],     Automatic}}
```

etc.

[image]